# How to make it as parallel processing using OpenMP flag?

Tags: linux, qt, openmp, pragma

How can we use all processor at a time to run below code using openmp flag?

If I am converting while loop as for loop using `for(;!xml.atEnd();)` it is showing error:

> need to initialisation and increment/decrements

```
//Need parallel processing for this code.  
 while (!xml.atEnd()) {
      // cerr <<"while loop";
      xml.readNext();
      if (xml.isStartElement()) {
          currentXmlElement = xml.name();


          if (xml.name() == "sample") {
              QString fname   = xml.attributes().value("filename").toString();
              QString sname   = xml.attributes().value("name").toString();
              QString setname   = xml.attributes().value("setName").toString();
              QString sampleOrder   = xml.attributes().value("sampleOrder").toString();
              QString isSelected   = xml.attributes().value("isSelected").toString();
              //_mainwindow->setStatusText(tr("Loading sample: %1").arg(sname));
              //_mainwindow->setProgressBar(tr("Loading Sample Number %1").arg(++currentSampleCount),currentSampleCount,currentSampleCount+1);

              bool checkLoaded=false;
              Q_FOREACH(mzSample* loadedFile, _mainwindow->getSamples()) {
                  if (QString(loadedFile->fileName.c_str())== fname) checkLoaded=true;
              }

              if(checkLoaded == true) continue;  // skip files that have been loaded already
              // #pragma omp critical {
              qDebug() << "Checking:" << fname;
              QFileInfo sampleFile(fname);

              if (!sampleFile.exists()) {
                  Q_FOREACH(QString path, pathlist) {
                      fname= path + QDir::separator() + sampleFile.fileName();
                      qDebug() << "Checking if exists:" << fname;
                      if (sampleFile.exists())  break;
                  }
              }

              if ( !fname.isEmpty() ) {
                  // mzFileIO* fileLoader = new mzFileIO(this);
                  // fileLoader->setMainWindow(_mainwindow);
                  // mzSample* sample = fileLoader->loadSample(fname);
                  // delete(fileLoader);

                  mzSample* sample = _mainwindow->fileLoader->loadSample(fname);
                  if (sample) {
                      _mainwindow->addSample(sample);
                      currentSample=sample;
                      if (!sname.isEmpty() )        sample->sampleName = sname.toStdString();
                      if (!setname.isEmpty() )          sample->setSetName(setname.toStdString());
                      if (!sampleOrder.isEmpty())     sample->setSampleOrder(sampleOrder.toInt());
                      if (!isSelected.isEmpty())        sample->isSelected = isSelected.toInt();
                  } else {
                      currentSample=NULL;
                  }
              }
          }

    //change sample color
          if (xml.name() == "color" && currentSample) {
              currentSample->color[0]   = xml.attributes().value("red").toString().toDouble();
              currentSample->color[1]   = xml.attributes().value("blue").toString().toDouble();
              currentSample->color[2]   = xml.attributes().value("green").toString().toDouble();
              currentSample->color[3]  = xml.attributes().value("alpha").toString().toDouble();
          }

    //polynomialAlignmentTransformation vector
          if (xml.name() == "polynomialAlignmentTransformation" && currentSample) {
      vector<double>transform;
      Q_FOREACH(QXmlStreamAttribute coef, xml.attributes() ) {
        double coefValue =coef.value().toString().toDouble();
        transform.push_back(coefValue);
      }
      qDebug() << "polynomialAlignmentTransformation: "; printF(transform);
      currentSample->polynomialAlignmentTransformation = transform;
      currentSample->saveOriginalRetentionTimes();
      currentSample->applyPolynomialTransform();
    }
      }
      if (xml.isCharacters() && currentXmlElement == "projectDescription") {
          projectDescription.append( xml.text() );
      }
  }
```

Comment: Reduced indentation

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP doesn't really deal with arbitrary objects. Besides, the OpenMP model won't suit you here. The basic idea for OpenMP is to farm out single iterations of a for loop to different threads. This isn't going to work well for reading XML data, which by its very nature has to be read serially to preserve ordering.

In your case, suppose you could use OpenMP, parallelizing the outer loop. Suppose there are 8 OpenMP threads running. Each is going to execute the `xml.readNext();` line. I can almost guarantee that the `readNext` function isn't thread-safe, which is going to give you undefined results. Even if it were thread-safe, it would have to read one full item (not sure what it's reading since I don't know the type of `xml`) atomically which would make your code mostly serial anyway.